# how to use ctakes in R

Tags: r, nlp, ctakes

I am planning to use Ctakes in R for NLP tasks.But I am not clear on how to create a pipeline or use Ctakes in R? Can someone point me to a step by step procedure on how to use cTakes in R?

Comment: Hi @tejkiran. Did you get anywhere with this? I'd also love to know...

Comment: @SebastianZeki Any success for you? I am also trying CTAKES API + Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON, Res API Based Ctakes](https://github.com/GoTeamEpsilon/ctakes-rest-service)
Check out this way of exposing ctakes through JSON & Rest API, you can then use GET/PUT from HTTR to call ctakes with clinical text you want to process.

  Follow instructions to install Ctakes as rest api

  Check out localhost:8080/ctakes-web-rest/

  Call rest services from R/Python by passing clinical text as query params

  Get ctakes output as JSON